# Error in Evaluate when selecting more than one cell: Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, mismatch

I evaluate for valid emails in Column M and the code works...

Except when I do anything anywhere in the sheet, Column M or elsewhere, that involves more than one cell - such as copying or pasting multiple cells, selecting and deleting multiple rows, etc., I get the error message

> "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch"

Debugging points to this code.

```
If Target.Column = 13 And Target.Value <> "" And _
  Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & Target.Address & ",""*@*.*"")") <> 1 Then
    Target.ClearContents
    Target.Activate
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid email address."
End If
```

I'd like to keep the code but prevent the errors when I am only deleting or pasting multiple cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `target.Cells.CountLarge` if more than one cell is selected or to add it to your code it could look like that

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
    ' Your code goes here
End If
```

**Update**: Your code should look like that

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then

    ' This is your code, right?
    If Target.Column = 13 And Target.Value <> "" And Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & Target.Address & ",""*@*.*"")") <> 1 Then
        Target.ClearContents
        Target.Activate
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid email address."
    End If

End If
```

**Remark**: As the OP did not post his complete code I assume this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13861640/6600940) was taken into consideration

Comment: Still getting the same error. How exactly does that paste in? I'm a true amateur with this, but when I post that in, anywhere in my code, I have trouble because my code is already an "IF" function. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @LorenScholes put your code where it says `' Your code goes here`

Comment: @Storax. Thank you very much! I was not aware of that particular post, but I have it bookmarked now or future reference. I have worked hours to resolve this issue. Wish I could give you more than one upvote.